# Transform table and its child tables to XML and back?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

What is the correct `SQL` syntax to transform a table and its child tables (up to 3 levels deep) into XML and back?

Here is an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/da83b0) with sample table structure and data.

Comment: Plz provide some sample structure and dummy data...

Answer (score 1):

Try this to transform your table and its child tables to XML

```
SELECT  *
        ,(SELECT    *
            FROM    childtable1
            WHERE   maintable_id = maintable.id
            FOR XML PATH('childtable1'),TYPE,ELEMENTS)
        ,(SELECT    *
                    ,(SELECT * 
                        FROM    childtable3
                        WHERE   childtable2_id  =   childtable2.id
                        FOR XML PATH('childtable3'),TYPE,ELEMENTS)
            FROM    childtable2 
            WHERE   maintable_id  =   maintable.id
            FOR XML PATH('childtable2'),TYPE,ELEMENTS)
FROM    maintable 
FOR XML PATH('maintable'),ELEMENTS,ROOT('root')
```

Here each child table will be like a sub query of immediate main table.

Comment: That's a start! How can I specify that childtable1 and childtable2 are directly under maintable whilst childtable3 should be under childtable2?

Comment: Modified , plz chk now